# C# :Group XML data by date and find min Time

Tags: xml, c#-4.0, linq-to-xml

I need help to group by date and find the minimum time for each date.
Here, `updateTime` is an XML node. My application does not support LINQ.

```
**UpdateTime**
2014-01-18T23:04:51.223542
2014-01-18T16:39:36.030992
2014-01-18T04:33:44.307508
2014-01-17T22:47:01.163672
2014-01-17T15:57:26.389259
2014-01-17T06:19:41.422436
```

Comment: Can you show or tell us what *you* tried already, so we know where to assist?

Answer (score 0):

I used Enumerable Collection which includes Sort() method

```
            string input = "2014-01-18T23:04:51.223542 2014-01-18T16:39:36.030992 2014-01-18T04:33:44.307508 2014-01-17T22:47:01.163672 2014-01-17T15:57:26.389259 2014-01-17T06:19:41.422436";
            string[] timeArray = input.Split(new char[] { ' ' });
            List<DateTime> times = new List<DateTime>();
            foreach (string time in timeArray)
            {
                times.Add(DateTime.Parse(time));
            }
            times.Sort((x, y) => x.CompareTo(y));
            DateTime minTime = times[0];​
```

Comment: Not sure what separator you are using between times (space, linefeed).  Code may not work with your edits.  I could use a number of methods to split the text into a string array.  It may make sense to use Regex which can handle both spaces and returns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your suggestions.I am getting the data from XML.There is DateTime and associated result.I created a list with this output and grouped the list based on date and sorted them by time.Please suggest me for better options without using LINQ.

```
    //group result(roclis) by date and  minimum time for each date
                var resultDateTime = dom.SelectNodes("//b:Lab[b:TestAbbreviation='" + rocLis + "']/b:UpdateTime", mgrb);                   
                var dtList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Tuple<DateTime,string>>();
                var dtFilteredList = new System.Collections.Generic.List<Tuple<DateTime,string>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < resultDateTime.Count; i++)
                {
                    var resultTime = resultDateTime.Item(i).InnerText;
                    if (resultTime == "") continue;
                    DateTime rsltDtTime = Convert.ToDateTime(resultTime);
                    var labResult = dom.SelectSingleNode("//b:Lab[b:TestAbbreviation='" + rocLis + "'][b:UpdateTime='" + resultTime + "']/b:Result", mgrb);
                    string result = labResult.InnerText;
                    dtList.Add(Tuple.Create(rsltDtTime,result));  
                }
                for (int i = dtList.Count - 1; dtList.Count > 0; )
                {
                    DateTime tempDate = dtList[i].Item1.Date;
                    var selectDates = dtList.FindAll(x => x.Item1.Date == tempDate.Date);
                    selectDates.Sort((a, b) => a.Item1.CompareTo(b.Item1));
                    dtFilteredList.Add(Tuple.Create(selectDates[0].Item1, selectDates[0].Item2));
                    dtList.RemoveAll(x => x.Item1.Date == tempDate.Date);
                    i = dtList.Count - 1;
                }
```